# Part of the Web application doesn't run on Tomcat where as runs as planned on Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, tomcat6

A Web application running fantastic (as expected/planned) on Eclipse (Indigo); but a particular functionality<sup>1</sup> fails while deployed on Tomcat 6.0.

I had changed the environment settings of Tomcat as on Eclipse, but unfortunately it's still not working.

And the strange thing is that; while running in Eclipse the temp directory for Java is `TEMP` folder<sup>2</sup> of the User; where as while running on Tomcat the temp folder becomes `WINDOWS\TEMP` and that why new file couldn't be found and hence exception `FileNotFound` is getting fired. Why does this happen?

<sub>[1]: It's calling a non-Java application to convert files that are being uploaded to server.</sub>

<sub>[2]: Used for the aforesaid non-Java application for the file conversion.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat, when installed as a Windows service, is running under a different user account and thus uses different paths. Especially when running as system service there is no user directory. If you have a controlled environment you should set fixed paths, e.g. per environment variables or properties files, that both applications can share.

Comment: @his...thanks for your response.........pls do give me some help in settings...i mean how or what the settings you want me to specify???

Comment: Hi his.....sorry for the late reply....i re-started the server and it's working as expected...so not to mention...still it is not clear to me...i mean what was the problem???